# how can I with a bash script tell if Sticky bit and Setgid are on the file

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I am trying to make it more simple and easier for users to know if setgid or sticky bit are on the file permission by just writing setgid: ON/OFF sticky bit: ON/OFF how would I do that I know about `ls -ld` and `awk` but after that I dont know what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-g file` to see if the file exists and the `setgid` bit is set. Use `-u file` to see if the exists and its `setuid` bit is set. The "sticky bit" can be tested with `-k file`. Don't confuse `setuid` with it.

```
[ -g "$myfile" ] && printf "%s has setgid set\n" "$myfile"
[ -u "$myfile" ] && printf "%s has setuid set\n" "$myfile"
[ -k "$myfile" ] && printf "%s has sticky bit set\n" "$myfile"
```

See the [test](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) documentation (manpage)

Comment: can I put this in a if statement and say else OFF ?

Comment: cant i just echo it ?

Comment: @zellez yes, if the `echo` doesn't use any variable: `if [ -g "$file" ]; then echo setgid: ON; else echo setgid: OFF; fi`

Comment: yeah That is what i did

Comment: ty for your help and thanks for the warning about {$myfile}